# Laravel 5 set custom path in fallback_locale

Tags: laravel, locale

I have been loading language file from a custom path in controller like,

```
Lang::addNamespace('CUSTOM-LANG', base_path('resources/lang/Cliets/ClietName'));
```

All I want is that if there is a missing language line, It should load that line from the path i define in `fallback_locale`

Is there any way to change the `fallback_locale` setting to any custom path,

Currently in Config/app.php it is set as,

```
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

I just want to change it to load from my custom path like,

```
'fallback_locale' => 'Resources/Lang/Clients/Default/en',
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this. I just change my path to,

```
'fallback_locale' => '../Default/en',
```